Define Electromagnetic Tensor in xCoba
I'm trying to define electromagnetic tensor $F_{ab}$ in xCoba. Here's what I've done
ClearAll["Global`*"];
<< xAct`xTensor`;
$DefInfoQ = False;
$PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices;
DefManifold[M4, 4, IndexRange[a, m]];

<< xAct`xCoba`
DefChart[cart, M4, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {t[], x[], y[], z[]}, 
 ChartColor -> Red]
DefScalarFunction[R]
g = CTensor[
   DiagonalMatrix[{-1, R[t[]]^2, R[t[]]^2, R[t[]]^2}], {-cart, -cart}];
SetCMetric[g, cart, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 1, 0}];
cd = CovDOfMetric[g];

DefScalarFunction[{A0, A1, A2, A3}]
A = CTensor[{A0[t[]], A1[t[]], A2[t[]], A3[t[]]}, {-cart}];

Now I want to define electromagnetic tensor from electromagnetic four-potential $A_a$ as $F_{ab}=\partial_a A_b-\partial_b A_a$. I've tried
F[-a,-b]=cd[-a][A[-b]]-cd[-b][A[-a]]

But looks like it is wrong. It doesnt give me the right result for $F^{ab}$ when I type
F[a,b]


Indices must be used as WL patterns. The simplest possibility here is defining
F[a_, b_] := cd[a][A[b]] - cd[b][A[a]]

Then you can compute both
F[-a, -b]

and
F[a, b] // Simplify

Note that you can also do something like this
g[a, c] g[b, d] F[-c, -d] // ToCCanonical

to compute F[a, b]. ToCCanonical will sort the indices in the way you expect.
Using xAct pattern indices requires more care in general, and there are a number of functions prepared to handle them, like IndexSet.

It works, thanks a lot!
